# My boss is looking the other way, about my work-from-home?

Tags: management, communication, work-environment

I have lately been working from home more than before. Well, my boss allows us to take 4 work from home days per month.

But in my current situation, I really wanted more. So I emailed him that I plan to work from home much of time now (about half the month). And asked, "I intend to work from home. I hope this is Ok with you - please let me know"

But my boss didn't answer. But I *knew*  I did have flexibility about this point, because we are often remote.

So my hunch is that I am annoying my boss a bit. That I may be slowly easing my way into his doghouse, unbeknownst.

I tell myself "Well I did email him, and he did let me work from home many times prior."

But part of me worries about it.

Comment: Have you talked to him about it?

Answer (score 5):

It definitely depends on your local culture (wherever that is), your company culture, your team culture, and the rapport you have with your manager. However, unless you have the type of rapport that such a declaration would be acceptable, simply telling your boss you're taking more than he/she has allowed is not a great way to get what you want.

It would be better to provide your reasons, and request his/her approval. If approval is not granted, and you continue to do it, you're treading on thin ice, and could lose your privileges altogether (and even your job).

Answer (score 4):

Whether the boss is annoyed with you depends on whether you are working four days from home or whether you just took it upon yourself to go ahead and work more than four days from home.

If I were your boss, I'd be seriously annoyed with you for pushing the envelope. If your boss is the way I was, which is to hold it in until I explode, then you are in the doghouse with your boss.

I am wondering why you are asking this question here because you know your and how your boss reacts than any of us. The way you are acting, you are not asking for permission, you are TAKING permission and if I were your boss, I wouldn't like it at all. That gets worse if the four days per month were set as policy by the company and your boss has no authority to give you more than these four days. In which case, you are jerking your boss around.

When I introduced the high quality Toshiba laptops into my company in the early 1980's, people loved them because they could take their work home, especially since they were getting paid for every hpur they worked. And it was only a matter of time before part of the staff announced to their supervising partners that they'd be working from home on such and such a day. What made it work is that there was trust between the supervising partners and the staff and that at no time did the staff make the supervising partners feel that the staff was pushing it. And that we had no policy about working from home that had been set by top management.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two separate issues you need to address here.

1. Ability to work from home more frequently; and
2. Identifying if there are any performance issues for "annoying" your boss.

With regard to working from home, if he didn't respond on one email I would contact him one more time and get a definite okay.  Perhaps he didn't see the email for some reason, or was trying to get time to answer politely.  Ask again (perhaps by phone?) or by email and make *sure* it's okay rather than assuming.  It may also alleviate any concern of "annoying your boss".

To tackle the second point, you should schedule a performance review with your boss.  I don't know how frequently you have them or if you have had one recently but the best way to gauge your boss's feeling is to give them a forum to discuss it.  A performance review is a standard way of achieving this.  It may also give you some insight into if he believes there are issues with your working from home more frequently.

Answer (score 2):

> My boss is looking the other way, about my work-from-home?

From your question it appears:

- You are working from home more than company policy permits
- Your boss hasn't told you not to do so (yet)
- You sent an email about it, but haven't received any response

From that you seem to conclude that it is okay to work from home as much as you like.

You may be right that this is fine, and that the boss is "looking the other way". Or you may be incorrect and your boss is compiling a list of "Things Adel Does That Are Bad." The only one who will know for sure is your boss - and apparently he isn't saying anything yet.

Why are you and your boss avoiding the subject?

When you are both in the office next (perhaps you have a weekly one-on-one meeting?) have a quick private meeting. Bring the subject up directly. Ask "I mentioned that I would like to work from home more than 4 days per month. I sent you an email about that, but I haven't heard back. I assume that means I can, but I want to be sure it' okay."

Then, you'll have your definitive answer, you won't have to rely on someone looking the other way, and you cannot be accused (by your boss, by coworkers, by upper management) of breaking the rules.

You'll know if you are annoying your boss, slowly getting into his doghouse, or not. And you'll no longer need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting your boss in a potentially difficult situation. Looking at the wider picture, if everybody in the team decided to do the same as you would it cause a problem?

The company has rules regarding flexible working and they exist for a reason. Unless you have a very good reason to request more flexibility it will be difficult for your boss to agree to it. It sounds like he is turning a blind eye to this as maybe it works for everyone at the moment but this could be stopped instantly if necessary as it has never been authorised.

Your boss may well be getting annoyed with you if you think you can just make up your own rules, maybe he's avoiding a potential conflict but as soon as someone else points out you work from home more and demands the same he's the one who has to deal with it not you.